# Symfony 4 and Microservices

Tags: symfony, bundle, microservices, symfony4

Say I'm going to create few microservices: Alpha, Beta, Gamma.
In terms of Application structure using older Symfony version like 2, I'd create a bundle for each service, but bundles are no longer recommended in Symfony 4. So... Should I create separate repositories for every service or still create a bundles in a one App?

Comment: The question is very complex, I think.
How microservice should produce/consume data?
If you want to have shared entities/documents, then you can still use Bundles, even though they're not recommended anymore.
But I would create new repo for each new microservice, so they will be more independent. e.g.: if service A fails, service B still keeps being alive etc.

Comment: And I'm still able to have centralized repo for shared classes which are installed by composer as dependency

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you have different microservices, as in different applications, you will not need bundles. You can keep them in different repositories, but a common practice is to use a so called mono-repository. As the name suggests, with a mono-repository you keep all of the projects in a single repository. This has the benefit that changes spanning all projects can be done more easily and in sync. The drawback is that it requires more effort when managing and might cause additional overhead when building and deploying as it will not be easy to see which service has changed so must likely you rebuild all of them. There are a few books and presentations on mono-repositories you might want to check out. In short, Symfony does not restrict how you manage your services. You can have a single repository for all projects or multiple repositories.

If you want to serve all "services" through the same application, even without bundles, you can do so by using namespaces to separate the logic, e.g. for controllers:

```
my_app
- src
  - Controller
    - Alpha
      - IndexController
    - Beta
      - IndexController
```

This should work out of the Box with the default configuration and even if you deviate you can make things like argument resolvers work by just pointing the configuration to the correct folder. Obviously this will require you to make sure that code is not shared between services should you ever want to extract them into their own application. There are some static code analyis tools that help you with keeping your architecture clean, i.e. make sure Alpha does not use code from Gamma and vice versa.

If you want to separate the apps more clearly by doing something like this:

```
my_app
- src
  - AlphaApp
    - ...
  - BetaApp
    - ...
```

You can still do that but it will require more manual work and the recipes will not work anymore, requiring you to do manual changes to most configurations and moving around files. How to do it depends on whether you want a shared kernel or a separate kernel for each service, but if you go that route I recommend keeping separate projects in the same repository, as it will probably yield cleaner results and be less work.

Answer (score -2):

You can still create bundles in symfony4 though its not recommended by best practices. see https://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/creating-the-project.html

Comment: Well, I know, but it's still not clear how to use it for microservices